# Eclipse shortcut + ""

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I have been coding now, and accidently pressed a key, while writing a System.out.print();
I typed something like this: System.out.print("Hello, this is a line!" + "Bla bla");
and what it did, it added a + "");
What is the shortcut for this?

Comment: You probably just hit the enter key when your cursor was at the end of the string, just before the ending double quote.

Comment: By the way, to get the access to the list and configuration of all shortcuts in Eclipse, go to Window->Preferences->Keys. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you place a double quote, eclipse automatically closes it, and when you hit enter it closes that quote and appends next line with + " " .

It is not very clear what you want to ask, Is this what you want to know ?